# Extracting the bottom line of multiple .txt files

Tags: notepad++

I have a few hundred .txt files which follow a specific format, eg. 24 lines of header text then x amount of lines of data (the amount of lines vary with each file), followed by one blank line. The only line I'm interested in is the bottom row of data. More specifically, I need the bottom value of the second column of data.

The files are not tab delimited, but the first column after the header is "D  " (two spaces after the D).

So far I tried concatenating all the files and working with the concatenated file in notepad++ but have not found a way of marking the bottom row of data. Also my attempts at using macros fail on the 'find' option.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: unfortunately I am hindered by doing this on my work PC with no authorisation to download an IDE of any sort (as well as having little to no ability). My only tools are Excel and notepad++!

Comment: Using Notepad++ is probably the wrong way to go about this. It is easy in many programming and scripting languages. Even easier would be to use the Unix program "tail".

Comment: Since you're probably using Windows, you can use PowerShell, I'm not sure how your files are delimited but something like this would probably work. `dir *.txt | ForEach {Get-Content $_ -Tail 1} | %{$_.Split('  ')[1]}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can better use a `bash` script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in * #loop over files
do
   tail -n 2 "$f" | head -n 1
done
```

The program thus prints the one but last line of each file.

You can then run it using:

```
bash script.sh
```

And if you want to store the result in a file, use a redirection:

```
bash script.sh > outputfile
```

> **Note**: In the script the `*` means, matching any file. If all files are for instance `.txt` files, you can use `*.txt`.
>
> **Note**: you should run the script in the directory where the files are located.

Answer (score 0):

In other editor SynWrite, can do it, using Python script (enter lines in console pane, Ctrl+tilde).
Script function - `ed_handles`. Example of usage -

```
Here is example which prints all tabs contents: for h in ed_handles(): print('---'); print(Editor(h).get_text_all());
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer and comments, the best way would be using a script (**shell** or **Perl** that could be copied as standalone even if you don't have admin rights on the machine, or **bash** and **Powershell** which are integrated in Windows by default).

If you really want to use Notepad++, it's possible to replace the files by the data, it's possible.

I used the following example:

```
############
## HEADER ##
############
D  1 2 3
D  4 5 6
D  7 8 9
D  0 a b
(empty line)
```

The following replacement will change the files to the data of the 2nd column

- `Search` > `Find in Files` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- *Find what*: `.*D  .*D  \S+\s+(\S+).*`
- *Replace with:* `\1`
- *Filters:* `*.txt`
- *Directory:* Select the directory where you have the txt files (you can use `Follow current doc.` if one of the file is currently open in Notepad++)
- *Search Mode* set to `Regular expression` and `. matches newline` is checked

This will change the file to

```
a
```

> **Note**: Explanations of the regular expression
>
> - `.*D  .*D` corresponds to all the text until the last `D` (D with double space)
> - `\S\s+` corresponds to the first column of data and the space after it
> - (\S+) corresponds of the second column of data
> - `.*` corresponds to the rest